# How to return rows array data one by one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`this.state.rows` contains a number of data in array.

```js
labels: [this.state.rows.map(x => x.A), /*this.state.rows[0].A, this.state.rows[1].A*/],
```

How can I make the map return with data like in the comment?

Comment: `map` returns an array. So remove square braces

Comment: For array `this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)`, for CSV `this.state.rows.map(x => x.A).join(",")`

Comment: What you have would seem to do what you want. Please provide more detail about what you want and why what you're doing isn't what you want. Please also update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

You could in do three ways

```
labels: this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)
```

```
labels: [...this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)]
```

```
labels: [this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)].flat()
```

Comment: `labels: [...this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)]` and `labels: [this.state.rows.map(x => x.A)].flat()` are both completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
labels: this.state.rows.map(rows => rows['A'])
```